# Algorithm for Back substitution of LU Decompositions

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

As part of a larger solution, I've established that I've implemented something incorrectly regarding solving the system

$Uz=y$

Where U is the upper triangular submatrix resultant from an LU=A decomposition.

What I have is; (assuming zero based indexing)

$z_{n-1}=y_{n-1}/U_{n-1,n-1}$

$for\ i=n-2;i>=0;i--$

$\ \ t=0$

$\ \ for\ j=i+1; j<n; j++$

$\ \ \ \ t-=U_{i,j}y_j$

$\ \ z_i=(y_i-t)/=U_{i,i}$

This is coming from my reading of [Goulb and Van Loan](http://books.google.com/books?id=mlOa7wPX6OYC&pg=PA87#v=onepage&q&f=false) but I could be making a mistake.

In a nutshell, all the z values except for z[0] are correct.

Notes; the LU decomposition used is lower unitary i.e diag L are all 1,

For anyone interested in the larger problem [be my guest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695029/c-lu-complete-pivoting-decomposition-and-matrix-solver-something-isnt-right), but as far as I can see this is the last thing wrong.

POST-ANSWER UPDATE: Finished the [solver](http://wp.me/pKDYh-9D), thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've currently written it, it looks as if you're subtracting entities from `t`, and then subtracting it from `y(i)` (i.e., adding that total to `t`) before the division. I'd have done something like the following:

```
z(n-1)=y(n-1)/U(n-1, n-1);
for (i=n-2;i>=0;i--) {
t=y(i);
for (j=i+1;j<n;j++) t -= U(i, j)*y(j)
z(i)=t/U(i, i);
}
```

As a check for your code:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\0&4&5\\0&0&6\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}6\\9\\6\end{pmatrix}$$